# How to identify UITextFields and Keyboard Activity?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I've searched in the web but didn't found anything similar to what I want. So,I am creating an application and I need to recognize when the user leaves a specific UITextField,more clearly.when the user enters a value in the `UITextField` and after touch outside to dismiss the keyboard, I need to recognize that the `UITextField` has lost activity for,after I perform an action.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `UITextFieldDelegate` in the Apple docs. Specifically the methods `textFieldDidEndEditing:` and `textFieldShouldReturn:`. Hook up the specific UITextField to an outlet and assign its delegate to your viewController. Then in the delegate method, if you need to make sure it's a specific text field, compare it to the IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

write `UITextFieldDelegate` in .h file then after include the following method in .m file.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```